# What is the difference between _Application and Application

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word

Why is it that to use Word you define a variable like this:

```
Dim Word As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application
```

OR

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application Word;
```

Then set it like this:

```
Word = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
```

OR

```
Word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

Whats the difference between **Application** and **_Application**

I suspect one may be a class and the other an interface or one may be public and the other private but that still makes no sense to me.

I was hoping someone can explain it to me.  The more details the better.

Comment: [Application inherits from _Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.application.aspx) with the added ApplicationEvents_11_Event

Comment: @rory, you just made an infinite loop!  I click you link which brings me to my question so I click your link which brings me to my question . . .

Comment: @John -- google search indexing is fast.  Click on one of the other links.

Comment: @rory, if you haven't figured it out yet I did search before posting, which I ALWAYS do.  It can often be much quicker at getting an answer.  However the results you posted are unclear.  I know if someone understands something they can have trouble understanding what is a clear explanation and what isnt.  Fortunately Dirk was very helpful.

Comment: I actually can't believe people have answered this given their time here, it's a Google search, not a specific programming issue at all. We help with specific issues people are stuck with, **you don't have one**.

Comment: @Zaggler: I think Hans' answer proves your comment wrong. I'd bet you would not have found that in-depth information easily.

Comment: @Dirk Vollmar Nothing proves the comment wrong it's a fact it is not a programming problem at all, so do I really ***need to start posting links*** which will form over half Hans answer as well as yours? This information is out there, plenty of it. These questions are off topic you should know that... We are not a wesearchitforyou.com ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both are interfaces and the `Application` interface inherits from the `_Application` interface (together with the `ApplicationEvents4_Event` interface).

So when to use what? The difference is explained in MSDN (emphasis added):

**[Application interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application.aspx):**

```
[GuidAttribute("00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
public interface Application : _Application, 
    ApplicationEvents4_Event
```

> This is a .NET interface derived from a COM coclass that is required by managed code for interoperability with the corresponding COM object. **Use this derived interface to access all method, property, and event members of the COM object**. However, if a method or event you want to use shares the same name under the same COM object, cast to the corresponding primary interface to call the method, and cast to the latest events interface to connect to the event. Refer to this topic for information about the COM object.

**[_Application interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application_members.aspx)**:

```
[TypeLibType(4304)]
[Guid("00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[ComImport]
public interface _Application  { ... }
```

> This is a primary interface in a COM coclass that is required by managed code for interoperability with the corresponding COM object. **Use this primary interface only when the method you want to use shares the same name as an event of the COM object**; in this case, cast to this interface to call the method, and cast to the latest events interface to connect to the event. Otherwise, use the .NET interface that is derived from the COM coclass to access methods, properties, and events of the COM object.

**Practical consequences**

In short: Use `Application` and not `_Application` in your code, unless you have to because there is an ambiguity between a method name and an event name.

Such an ambiguity exists for example between the [`Application.Quit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_event.quit.aspx) event (fired when the application quits) and the [`Application.Quit(ref Object SaveChanges, ref Object OriginalFormat, ref Object RouteDocument)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.quit.aspx) method (exits the application, when called).

In order to call the method, you could simply write (e.g. to quit without prompting to save changes):

```
Application.Quit(false);
```

However, this might give you the following compiler warning:

> Warning 3 Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application.Quit(ref object, ref object, ref object)' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event.Quit'. Using method group.

To avoid the warning, you can cast the application object to the `_Application` interface:

```
((_Application)Application).Quit(false);
```

If you you want to subscribe to the event, you need to cast the application object to the appropriate event interface:

```
((ApplicationEvents4_Event)Application).Quit += OnApplicationQuit;

private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    // handle event here
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Short, precise, useful.

Answer (score 12):

It is kind of a long story, at break-neck speed.  COM uses a hyper-pure interface-based paradigm.  A client app only ever makes calls on interface members, the "coclass" that implements the interface is completely hidden from view.  All that is exposed is the guid of the coclass, the CLSID.  That is passed to the universal CoCreateInstance() factory function, it returns the interface you asked for.  This isolation is the primary reason that COM servers can be written in any language, none of its implementation details are visible so can never be incompatible with whatever language you use.

Working with interfaces was however a problem with early VB versions, unlike VB.NET they did not have any support for interfaces.  So their runtime support tricked it out and makes it *look* like you are working with a class.  Named `Application` in this case.  The members of that class are the members of the default interface, `_Application` in this case.  Any connection points from the default source interface are added as events.

The leading underscore in `_Application` is a trick as well, it tells type library browsers to hide the interface.  Something that the Object Browser in Visual Studio does not do, perhaps one reason you are asking this question.  One thing the trickery can't accomplish is dealing with a coclass that implements multiple interfaces.  But taken note of by the type designer, he made sure to give the coclass only one default interface and one source interface.

Similar trickery was necessary to give .NET programmers the same kind of api, ensuring that they too could use `Application` and get their code easily ported.  This is done by the type library importer (Tlbimp), it synthesizes an extra interface with the same name as the coclass, all of its members are exactly the same as the default interfaces.

This is an interface, the VB.NET and C# compilers allow you to create an instance of it.  Very unlike what you can do with a normal interface.  The importer *also* synthesizes a class, same name as the coclass with "Class" appended.  So `ApplicationClass` here.  It implements *all* of the interfaces that the coclass implements.  You have no practical use for it in VB.NET and you should avoid it since the very desirable "Embed Interop Types" feature doesn't support embedding it.  But you may want to use it in a language like F# or a language that was ported to .NET but doesn't support interfaces.

Long story short, `_Application` is the actual interface that came from the type library.  But you ought to favor the synthesized `Application`, best match with all code samples you'll ever encounter.